# Ubuntu 16.04 Speakers started to make noise

Tags: dual-boot, sound

I have a dual boot computer with Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Recently on the Ubuntu OS, the speakers in my laptop started to make a cracking noise when I turn on the sound volume too loud, like playing music. This does not happen when I boot up Windows, so I think that it is a software rather than a hardware error. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This could happen when you allow more than 100% on Output Volume on Sound Settings. Have you done that? It distorts the sound and that's a probable cause to your noise.